# Función asincrona devuelve undefined obteniendo con firebase react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native

Estoy intentando hacer un crud con react-native y firebase y al llamar la función asincrona que debería retornar los datos está devuelve undefined.

```
useEffect(() => {

(async () => {

  try {
    
    const entidades = firebaseService.getEntidades();

    console.log(entidades);

  } catch (e) {

    alert(e);

  }
})();
}, []);
```

y en el componente firebaseService tengo:

```
 // Función para obtener las entidades
   getEntidades = async () => {
    await this.db
      .ref("/entidades")
      .on("value", (querySnapShot) => {
        let data = querySnapShot.val() ? querySnapShot.val() : {};
        let entidadesArray = { ...data };

        // Console.log funciona obteniendo los datos
        console.log(entidadesArray)

      })
    return entidadesArray
  };
```

Comment: Agrega el código de error

Comment: No me genera error, devuelve undefined

Answer (score 0):

No es que te hace falta el `await` cuando haces `getEntidades()`?

```
useEffect(() => {

(async () => {

  try {
    
    const entidades = await firebaseService.getEntidades();//AQUI

    console.log(entidades);

  } catch (e) {

    alert(e);

  }
})();
}, []);
```

Que por cierto podrías hacer así:

```
useEffect(async() => {
  try {
    
    const entidades =  await firebaseService.getEntidades();

    console.log(entidades);

  } catch (e) {

    alert(e);

  }
}, []);
```